# How do I access chat?

Tags: support, chat

How do access the chat room to ask a question?

Comment: For future reference, putting useless text into a post just to fill up a character limit is frowned upon. A better alternative would be to get the extra characters from a description of what you already tried to figure out how to use the chat room.

Comment: Are you on pc or app?

Comment: I use a chromebook. *[removed side conversation --ACM]*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL is:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar

Alternatively on the main site click the down triangle near the top left of the page:

[image: Chat link]

and click on the word chat. Then click the link for the h Bar:

[image: h Bar]